# Safari displaying 2 icons on transform rotate

Tags: css, angular, sass, safari

So in a Angular project I have icons and dropdown components.
When dropdown is opened, icon that is used (arrow) gets .open class applied which does:

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

In the default state I have transition defined:

```
transition: transform 120ms $some-easing;
```

$some-easing is a variable that holds a specific cubic-bezier easing.

So this works fine in Chrome and Firefox but it doesn't work correct in Safari.

In Safari, animation is triggered and at the end of the animation both the default icon state and animated icons are displayed in the same place.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours of digging around, I found out that transform was applied to the component container and not the icon itself. Other browsers were fine with this, but not safari.

Solution is to move the transition and transform properties to the SVG element.